# Unable to use web-services function in R with SSOAP

Tags: r, web-services, soap

I'm trying to retrieve data to R from brazilian legislative chamber via their web-service platform, but I've got stuck. Although i'm able to have the functions assigned into R’s global environment I'm unable to use none of them.

This is what I've got so far:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(XMLSchema)
library(SSOAP)

url_wsdl = "http://www.camara.gov.br/SitCamaraWS/Proposicoes.asmx?WSDL"
wsdl <- getURL(url_wsdl, verbose = TRUE, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE, useragent = "R") 
doc = xmlParse(wsdl, asText = TRUE)
def <- processWSDL(doc)
ff  <- genSOAPClientInterface(def = def)

test <- ff@functions$ListarSiglasTipoProposicao()
```

and it generates

```
Error: 1: Space required after the Public Identifier
2: SystemLiteral " or ' expected
3: SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing
```

when it should generates the content cretaed after clicking "Invoke" on this link: http://www.camara.gov.br/SitCamaraWS/Proposicoes.asmx?op=ListarSiglasTipoProposicao

Does anyone have any suggestions on what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You require a user agent otherwise the site is rejecting the request:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(XMLSchema)
library(SSOAP)

url_wsdl = "http://www.camara.gov.br/SitCamaraWS/Proposicoes.asmx?WSDL"
wsdl <- getURL(url_wsdl, verbose = TRUE, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE, useragent = "R") 
doc = xmlParse(wsdl, asText = TRUE)
def <- processWSDL(doc)
ff  <- genSOAPClientInterface(def = def)

myAgent <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
.opts = list(useragent = myAgent)
test <- ff@functions$ListarSiglasTipoProposicao(.opts = .opts
                                                , .convert = function(x){x})


> test
<ListarSiglasTipoProposicaoResult>
  <siglas xmlns="">
  <sigla tipoSigla="AA        " descricao="Autógrafo" ativa="True" genero="o"/>
  <sigla tipoSigla="ADD       " descricao="Adendo" ativa="True" genero="o"/>
  <sigla tipoSigla="ANEXO     " descricao="Anexo" ativa="True" genero="o"/>
  .......

> str(test)
Classes 'XMLInternalElementNode', 'XMLInternalNode', 'XMLAbstractNode' <externalptr>
```

Here we stipulate a very simple function to manipulate the content. We can give a better conversion function to get a more likeable result:

```
test <- ff@functions$ListarSiglasTipoProposicao(.opts = .opts
            , .convert = function(x){
              out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(getNodeSet(x, "//sigla"), xmlAttrs))
              as.data.frame(out, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
              })
> head(test)
tipoSigla         descricao ativa genero
1 AA                AutÃ³grafo  True      o
2 ADD                   Adendo  True      o
3 ANEXO                  Anexo  True      o
4 APJ              Anteprojeto  True      o
5 ATC        Ato ConvocatÃ³rio  True      o
6 ATOP       Ato do Presidente False      o
```

The encoding is tricky as `xmlAttrs` doesnt have an encoding argument unlike `xmlValue` but you can try the following (cross platform it may not work I only have a windows box to test with currently):

```
myFunc <- function(x){
  input <- SSOAP:::parseSOAP(x$content)
  out <- lapply(getNodeSet(input, "//sigla"), function(x){iconv(xmlAttrs(x), "UTF-8", "UTF-8")})
  out <- do.call(rbind, out)
  as.data.frame(out, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
class(myFunc) <- "RawSOAPConverter"
test <- ff@functions$ListarSiglasTipoProposicao(.opts = .opts, .convert = myFunc)

> head(test)
tipoSigla         descricao ativa genero
1 AA                 Autógrafo  True      o
2 ADD                   Adendo  True      o
3 ANEXO                  Anexo  True      o
4 APJ              Anteprojeto  True      o
5 ATC         Ato Convocatório  True      o
6 ATOP       Ato do Presidente False      o
```

Comment: Right on, you've got it! Thanks for the help and for the tip on how to get a more friendly result (though I'm still trying to handle the utf-8 characters).
Just for curiosity: why do you need the ", .convert = function(x){x}" in the first case?

Comment: If you try running without it it returns basically an empty object. To debug I called `debugonce` on `SSOAP::.SOAP` and called `ff@functions$ListarSiglasTipoProposicao()`. That was how I found the need for a user-agent. Adding a user-agent and calling `ff@functions$ListarSiglasTipoProposicao(.opts = .opts)` gave an empty object. Calling `debugonce` on `SSOAP::.SOAP` once again identified the need for a `.convert` function. Possibly `SSOAP` expects a proper SOAP response by default see for example http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_soap_example.asp where as here we are returned XML.

Comment: Added a possible approach with regards to the encoding.

Comment: Great! That works perfectly. Just changed the "input <- SSOAP:::parseSOAP(test$content)" to "input <- SSOAP:::parseSOAP(x$content)"